# How can i hide address bar in ChromePortable

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I would like to hide menu buttons, navigation buttons and address bar in ChromePortable.

Can i do so? Is it possible ?

I'm trying to use Jetty + war + ChromePortable as desktop application. Any suggestions about that?